# which references has to be adde when using VB-JSON parser

Tags: json, parsing, ms-access, vba

I am using [VB-JSON parser](http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html) to get data from an API and saving the data in MS access table.

When I imported the bas file in my ms-access project and compiled it, I am getting error on the following line of code

```
Public Function RStoJSON(rs As ADODB.Recordset) As String
```

[image: JSON Parser error when compiling]

I have added following references in access -

[image: References in project]

Answer (score 1):

That is: Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.0 Library